# Is it necessary to specify every superclass in a class context of a class declaration?

Tags: haskell

The `ArrowList` class from the hxt package has the following declaration:

`class (Arrow a, ArrowPlus a, ArrowZero a, ArrowApply a) => ArrowList a where` ...

The `ArrowPlus` class is declared as:
`class ArrowZero a => ArrowPlus a where` ...

The `ArrowZero` class is declared as:
`class Arrow a => ArrowZero a where` ...

And the `ArrowApply` class is declared as:
`class Arrow a => ArrowApply a where` ...

Why can't it just be written as:
`class (ArrowPlus a, ArrowApply a) => ArrowList a where` ...?

Comment: This is interesting... I thought it could.

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to include all the superclasses. If you write

```
class (ArrowPlus a, ArrowApply a) => ArrowList a where
```

it will work. However, here are two possible reasons for mentioning all the superclasses explicitly.

1. It might be more readable as you can tell at a glance what all the superclasses are.
2. It might be *slightly* more efficient, as listing the superclasses explicitly will result in a direct dictionary lookup at runtime, while for a transitive superclass it will first lookup the dictionary for the superclass and then lookup the class member in that.

   For example, take this inheritance chain:

   ```
   module Example where

   class Foo a where
       foo :: a -> String

   class Foo a => Bar a
   class Bar a => Baz a
   class Baz a => Xyzzy a

   quux :: Xyzzy a => a -> String
   quux = foo
   ```

   Looking at the generated core for this (with `ghc -c -ddump-simpl`), we see that this generates a chain of lookup calls. It first looks up the dictionary for `Baz` in `Xyzzy`, then `Bar` in that, then `Foo`, and finally it can look up `foo`.

   ```
   Example.quux
     :: forall a_abI. Example.Xyzzy a_abI => a_abI -> GHC.Base.String
   [GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs]
   Example.quux =
     \ (@ a_acE) ($dXyzzy_acF :: Example.Xyzzy a_acE) ->
       Example.foo
         @ a_acE
         (Example.$p1Bar
            @ a_acE
            (Example.$p1Baz @ a_acE (Example.$p1Xyzzy @ a_acE $dXyzzy_acF)))
   ```

   Modifying the definition of `Xyzzy` to explicitly mention `Foo`:

   ```
   class (Foo a, Baz a) => Xyzzy a
   ```

   We see that it can now get the `Foo` dictionary straight from the `Xyzzy` one and look up `foo` in that.

   ```
   Example.quux
     :: forall a_abD. Example.Xyzzy a_abD => a_abD -> GHC.Base.String
   [GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs]
   Example.quux =
     \ (@ a_acz) ($dXyzzy_acA :: Example.Xyzzy a_acz) ->
       Example.foo @ a_acz (Example.$p1Xyzzy @ a_acz $dXyzzy_acA)
   ```

   Note that this may be GHC-specific. Tested with version 7.0.2.

Comment: Wouldn't it be worth a compiler optimization to propagate those constraints to the subclasses?

Comment: @FUZxxl: I'd think so, yes. The only downside I can see is that the dictionaries would get slightly bigger, but that's not gonna be an issue unless you have a gigantic inheritance tree.